# javascript date format issue

Tags: javascript, date

I'm not able to find cause of this behavior

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var d1 = Date.parse("02/11/2014");
var d2 = Date.parse("2014-02-11");
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=d1+"---------"+d2+"<br/>"+new Date(d1)+"----"+"<br/>"+new Date(d2);

}
</script>
```

**OUTPUT:**

1392057000000---------1392076800000

Tue Feb 11 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

Tue Feb 11 2014 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

Why it gives different time when I pass same date in Date.parse() ?

JSBIN shared at: http://jsbin.com/IfufAToX/1/

Comment: I think there is duplicate exists I have crossed, where there is a nice explanation. let me try to find it

Comment: please point that duplicate.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse

Comment: @Praveen Jeganathan this question is not duplicate that.

Comment: The format supplied infers a locale, so you're going to be off by GMT [offset] depending on how you present the date.

Comment: This has to do with your location

Comment: YES it is already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse

Comment: Here's more about it: http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/03/javascript-and-dates-what-mess.html

Answer (score 0):

it's all about how you will write the template, I mean

YYYY-MM-DD, or what ever else

Let's take a look what official ecma says:
first of all we go [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) 
next w go [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2)

hope that helps.

Comment: I downvoted this at first, but that was a bit too harsh perhaps. Your answer is rather poor compared to the ones in the duplicate, and you didn't really explain it all that well. Linking to the spec is fine, but try to include the essence in your answer here. Links can expire, and a spec can be hard to understand for novice developers.